# Pythonic way to handle errors while working with dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, error-handling, exception

in my application, I take data from a database and perform calculations on it. The data is then sent over an API to the Frontend of my application.

After reading the data from the DB I have a dictionary like this:

```
{"a":5, "b":0}
```

I then have a function like this that takes the dictionary as an input and adds more keys, which values are calculated from the other keys.

```
function dict_calc(data_dict):
    data_dict["c"] = data_dict["a"] / data_dict["b"]
    data_dict["d"] = data_dict["a"] * data_dict["b"]
    return data_dict
```

My problem is that if there is an error (the example above would throw a ZeroDevisionError) then I still want to keep the data in key "d" but still need a way to tell the end user or the frontend that something went wrong. One Idea I came up with is this:

```
try:
    data_dict["c"] = data_dict["a"] / data_dict["b"]
except ZeroDivisionError:
    if data_dict["a"] == 0:
        data_dict["c"] = {"msg":"Datapoints a & b are 0."}
    else:
        data_dict["c"] = {"msg":"Datapoint b is 0."}
data_dict["d"] = data_dict["a"] * data_dict["b"]
return data_dict
```

But now all the code down the road needs a way to pass along the msg dictionary in the dictionary.

Is there a better way to pass along an indicator for "invalid" data other than my msg dictionary?

Greetings,
c3ntry

Comment: Why not use `None` (edit: or better yet, `float('nan')`) if there's no result for the division?

Comment: Typically I would imagine `0` or `nan` values would be used (not `None` I would say, since this isn't even a numeric type)

Comment: How about `data_dict['c'] = None` ?

Comment: For the division, 'None' would be sufficient but what if my data_dict["b"] and data_dict["a"] both being 0 results in a different error than only data_dict["b"] being 0? (I will update the question to clarify)

Comment: @c3ntry Dividing by 0 will always give the same error, even if the numerator is also 0.

Comment: I am aware, but I meant if more from a business logic perspective. Or is this the wrong place to generate business logic level errors?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps,

Actually, we have 2 problems,

- We dont want any extra data variable inside the dict if an error occurs.
- We want to inform the user about any such error.

One way to go around this is having a queue which holds error messages for us, until asked.

`from queue import Queue
error = Queue()
try:
    data_dict["c"] = data_dict["a"] / data_dict["b"]
except ZeroDivisionError:
    if data_dict["a"] == 0:
        error.put('Datapoints a & b are 0.')
    else:
        error.put('Datapoints b is 0.')
data_dict["d"] = data_dict["a"] * data_dict["b"]
return data_dict`

After you return to the function call, use `error.get()` to inform the user.
Here, there is an issue, i.e dict['c'] will not be created in the dict you pass.
so wherever possible, use, `dict.get('c',(default_value))`
where default_value is value to be returned if 'c' doesnt exists.